Infinite loop on path finding algorithm (Hidato Puzzle)
import random as r

class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.out = []
        self.is_on_path = False
        self.path_out = None
        self.is_source = True
        self.label = 0
        self.is_hole = False

    def add_edge(self, that):
        arc = Arc(self, that)
        self.out.append(arc.reverse)
        that.out.append(arc)

class Arc:
    def __init__(self, head, tail):
        self.head = head
        if tail is not None:
            self.reverse = Arc(tail, None)
            self.reverse.reverse = self
        else:
            self.reverse = None

def find_path(nodes, holes):
    for node in nodes:
        node.is_on_path = False

    # picking random starting point
    while True:
        #sink = r.choice(nodes)
        num = r.randint(0, len(nodes) - 1)
        print(num)
        sink = nodes[num]
        if sink.is_hole == False: #------ problem might be here
            break
        else:
            sink = None
    #sink = r.choice(nodes)
    #print(f"final num :{num}")
    sink.is_on_path = True

    is_not_on_path_count = len(nodes) - 1 - len(holes) # total number of nodes - 1

    while is_not_on_path_count > 0:
        sink.path_out = r.choice(sink.out) #sink.out is neighbors of current node
        print(f"current Sink: {nodes.index(sink)}")
        sink = sink.path_out.head #sink is now the head of the path_out
        print(f"going Sink: {nodes.index(sink)}")

        if sink.is_on_path:# backtracking
            sink = sink.path_out.head
            reverseA = None
            node = sink

            while True:
                temp = node.path_out
                node.path_out = reverseA
                reverseA = temp.reverse
                node = temp.head

                if node==sink:# and reverseA is not None:
                    break

        else:
            sink.is_on_path = True
            is_not_on_path_count -= 1
        print("-"*30)
def label_path(nodes):
    for node in nodes:
        if node.is_hole == False:
            node.is_source = False
        node.is_source = True

    for node in nodes:
        if(node.path_out is not None):
            node.path_out.head.is_source = False
    
    source = None

    for node in nodes:
        if node.is_source and node.is_hole == False:
            source = node
            break

    count = 0
    while(True):
        # if source.is_hole == False:
        count += 1
        source.label = count
        if source.path_out is None:
            break
        source = source.path_out.head

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    n = 3 # width
    m = 3 # height

    table = [[Node() for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(m)]

    holes = [[1,  1], [2, 2]]
    for hole in holes:
        table[hole[0]][hole[1]].is_hole = True

    nodes = [table[i][j] for i in range(m) for j in range(n)] # this is flatened table (not 2d array)
    
    # populating edges (connecting all neighbors)
    for i in range(len(table)):
        for j in range(len(table[i])):
            
            # if the hole is in this shits then skip loop
            if [i, j] in holes:
                table[i][j].is_hole = True
                continue

            if i >= 1:

                # top left edge 
                if j >= 1:
                    if[i-1, j-1] not in holes:
                        table[i-1][j-1].add_edge(table[i][j])

                # top edge
                if[i-1, j] not in holes:
                    table[i-1][j].add_edge(table[i][j])

                # top right edge
                if j < len(table[i]) - 1: # for very right edge
                    if[i-1, j+1] not in holes:
                        table[i-1][j+1].add_edge(table[i][j])
            
            # left edge
            if j >= 1:
                if[i, j-1] not in holes:
                    table[i][j-1].add_edge(table[i][j])
    
    # print all nodes and their neighbors and i want the coordinates of the nodes and there neighbors
    # print all nodes and their neighbors and their coordinates
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            node = table[i][j]
            print(f"Node: ({i}, {j})")
            print("Neighbors:")
            for neighbor in node.out:
                neighbor_index = nodes.index(neighbor.head)
                print(f"  Neighbor: {neighbor_index}")
            print()


    find_path(nodes, holes)
    label_path(nodes)

    #display
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            print(f"{table[i][j].label:6d}", end="")
        print()

I am trying to create a Hidato puzzle generator. however i am running into a bit of a trouble
--------------------------------------------------------------------
fyi a solved hidato puzzle consists of constitutive numbers being neighbors. somewhat like 
4 8 9
3 5 7
2 1 6 
hidato puzzles can also have holes where your not allowed to use that node like the following (0 is the hole) 
8 1 2 
7 0 3 
6 5 4 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
once i implemented the holes i started getting an infinite loop in the find_path() function. specifically i believe its the backtracking while loop in there however it can be a number of things there.
if someone could please find the solution to this bug. that would be greatly appreciated (i am Canadian)
also DFS would not work as its not scalable. it would do the small grids but for something like 7 x 7 or above, DFS is just too slow.
i have to credit the following post as it did serve as inspiration for this code
ran into trouble once i implemented holes for the puzzle. otherwise the code is identical to the other post linked. and the infinite loop is not on every run. only on certain runs

"if someone can please find the bug" - This seems out of scope, I'm afraid. SO is more of a knowledge base than a help center, and bug-finding (as opposed to bug-fixing) questions tend to be less useful to future users, even if they're useful to you.

@AndrewYim dually noted. thanks. will keep that in mind!

I have no idea how the program is actually supposed to work, but nodes contains the holes too. Is it supposed to?

@TedLyngmo the nodes have an attribute if they are a hole .is_hole its set as false by default but when initializing the grid for the listed coors in holes  those coors the attribute is set to true. but why? its so the initial starting point of the path is not created on a hole which is just a node with no neighbors. same goes for labeling the path. for how the program works basically I start by creating a flattened array of nodes. where each node knows there neighbors in .out attribute and from there i am kinda creating a linked list of the possible path.

Ok, I see that you have a while loop in find_path  that finds a random starting point but excludes the holes. It just would have seemed easier if the holes wasn't in the nodes list at all.

@TedLyngmo you do make a valid point. honeslty the only reason i kept it in. is so even with holes it can maintain its original grid shape. also i just  didn't think of that in the process

Your backtracking is not backtracking: it reverses the path you found to then extend it on the other end, but that is not how backtracking is supposed to work.

@trincot my apologies. you're right with your statement. I thought it was the same thing  but clearly it is not. You learn something new every day! ( i am just a student who just started learning DSA :)

Another thing: In the connecting all neighbors part, it seems you make up to 4 connections, not 8, so it's not connecting all neighbours. Is that on purpose?

@TedLyngmo yes each node is only making 4 connections but if you look at the .add_edge method. it makes sure that if node a is neighbors to node b. the .add_edge makes sure to go to node b and store node a as a neighbor for that. cause each node if just populating , top-left, top, top-right, and right and its populating the edges starting top left of the grid. so the nodes that are not at the "edge" of the grid end up having all 8 neighbors, unless there is a hole.

Ok, it would be clearer if the connections were made in one place. for pos in valid_neighbouring_positions(m, n, i, j): neighbour = table[pos[0]][pos[1]] if not neighbour.is_hole: neighbour.add_edge(table[i][j])

The problem is in the way you implemented backtracking: this reverses the direction of the path found so far, and then lets the search continue from the other end of the path. But this is not how backtracking works. This actually tries to make progress without ever really backtracking. Moreover, this process can get stuck when both ends of the path have no possibility to select an unvisited node. In that case your code will keep reversing nodes on the same path infinitely.
Backtracking means you really shorten the path by unlinking from it the most recently added node, and then trying another neighbor. If all neighbors were already tried, then you would backtrack even more... etc.
A straightforward way to implement backtracking is through recursion.
There are some other things to remark about your code, including:

The Arc class is overkill: just store a list of neighbor nodes in out.
You're marking hole nodes in two different loops. You can drop the first one of these and just leave it for the second loop to do this.
The first  loop in label_path sets is_source to False in the if block, but then immediately sets it to True. This makes little sense.
You could label the nodes during the search and use the label value to indicate that a node is on the path (> 0) or not (= 0).
Using .index() to find a node's index to print it is a bit clumsy. Instead give nodes an attribute that can serve to print it, and implement __repr__ (or __str__)
Retrying your random selection until it is not a hole can be improved upon: select the nodes that are not holes first, and then randomly select from that.
To make sure you find a path if it exists, try all nodes as starting nodes until you have success. This is not the most efficient way to solve it, but that is only a problem if your grid is large with relatively few holes.
You don't really need to link nodes to represent the path. By setting the label attributes you implicitely define it. No need for is_on_path, path_out or is_source attributes.

Here is your code with those remarks taken on board:
import random as r

class Node:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name   # To ease identifying nodes (cf. repr), give them their id
        self.out = []
        self.label = 0
        self.is_hole = False

    def add_edge(self, that):  # Just store neighbors, no Arc needed
        self.out.append(that)
        that.out.append(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.name)


def find_path(nodes):
    unused_nodes = [node for node in nodes if not node.is_hole]
    n = len(unused_nodes)

    def dfs(node, count):
        if node.label:
            return False  # Not a valid continuation of path
        count += 1
        node.label = count  # This also marks the node as on the path
        if count == n:
            return [node]  # We're done!

        neighbors = node.out[:]
        r.shuffle(neighbors)  #  Only needed if you need randomness
        if any(dfs(neighbor, count) for neighbor in neighbors):
            return True
        node.label = 0  # Backtrack
        return False
    
    # Try all non-hole nodes as starting points, until success
    r.shuffle(unused_nodes)  #  Only needed if you need randomness
    return any(dfs(node, 0) for node in unused_nodes)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 3
    m = 3
    
    table = [[Node((x,y)) for y in range(n)] for x in range(m)]

    holes = [[1, 1], [2, 2]]

    nodes = [table[i][j] for i in range(m) for j in range(n)]

    for i, row in enumerate(table):  # Use enumerate
        for j, node in enumerate(row):
            if [i, j] in holes:
                node.is_hole = True  # Only set here
                continue

            if i >= 1:
                if j >= 1 and [i-1, j-1] not in holes:  # Use AND instead of nested IFs
                    table[i-1][j-1].add_edge(node)
                if [i-1, j] not in holes:
                    table[i-1][j].add_edge(node)
                if j < len(table[i]) - 1 and [i-1, j+1] not in holes:  # Use AND
                    table[i-1][j+1].add_edge(node)
            if j >= 1 and [i, j-1] not in holes:  # Use AND
                table[i][j-1].add_edge(node)

    for node in nodes:
        print(f"Node: {node} has these neighbors:")
        for neighbor in node.out:
            print(f"  {neighbor}")
        print()

    if not find_path(nodes):
        print("failed to find a path")

    for row in table:
        for cell in row:
            print(f"{cell.label:6d}", end="")
        print()


hi @trincot. you do make valid points. and yes a DFS solution is a quick and elegant solution. however once i start scaling the grid to something like a 7 x 7 or 9 x 9. dfs is simply not fast enough. please read the post i referenced in my in my post, as that would explain alot of the points you talked about, and i looked through my code i am only marking holes once, the other times i am just checking.

Well I pointed out where you definitely went wrong. You don't have to go for a dfs solution though. Please edit your question to specify what the maximum grid size is with an example input of that size.
